# How to do soft delete using JPA query with spring api?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

Hi I am a beginner in Java spring boot. I was trying to modify a particular record using :

```
adminRepo.updateAllActive(id);    // method Call
```

Repository:

```
@Query(value= "update admin a set a.active = 0 where a.id = :id " ,nativeQuery=true)
AdminEntity updateAllActive(@Param("id") Integer id);
```

But I am getting error "Could not extract Resultset"

Can anyone guide me for this. I am able to read entries from database.Issue only occurs when i try any modification query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQL `UPDATE` does not return a `ResultSet`, but `@Query` expects a `ResultSet`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update query returns an integer value indicating the number of affected entries and can be overwritten to return void, so you should declare your method return type as void if you don't care about the count:

```
@Modifying
@Query(value= "update admin a set a.active = 0 where a.id = :id" ,nativeQuery=true)
void updateAllActive(@Param("id") Integer id);
```

Also you need to mark your query as `@Modifying`, for more info regarding update queries refer to [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.modifying-queries).

Answer (score 1):

Add `@Modifying` annotation, and declare your method to return `int`.

See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.modifying-queries

Answer (score 0):

Example

```
  @Modifying
    @Query("Update Users u SET u.userKey=:userKey, u.phoneNumberVerified=true, u.name=:name, u.surname=:surname, u.phoneNumberVerified=true WHERE u.phoneCode=:phoneCode AND u.phoneNumber=:phoneNumber ")
    void updateUsers(@Param("userKey") String userKey, @Param("phoneCode") String phoneCode,
            @Param("phoneNumber") String phoneNumber, @Param("name") String name, @Param("surname") String surname);
```

Let me know if it correct